# Google indexing not working

Tags: seo, google-search-console, google-search

I have recently created my website and hosted it through 000webhost. I have also begun researching on how to make my website 'searchable' from googles search engine.

And so i came across google webmasters and its tools. I created a sitemap and submitted it, and added the needed tags to my website head.

I then asked google to fetch and render my links that i wanted google to have appear when searched for, as shown below:

http://snag.gy/Qc8J3.jpg

As soon as it said that my web links were indexed i could search for my website with almost all of my meta tag searches and find it on the two listed pages. A few days later, after using the same search parameters i can no longer find my website, so i went to my index status and it now says that it is currently indexing 0 links as shown below:

http://snag.gy/m2euX.jpg

I dont understand why this is? and also how can i get my website indexed by google for me to search for it?

Comment: It just plain takes a while. Search engines are notoriously slow. It can take months. As long as Google can reach your site, you are okay. BTW- sitemaps a generally ignored except to compare that Google can properly crawl your site. The exceptions are very very large sites, sites with a paywall or login, or any situation where Google cannot see all of your pages. In short, submitting a sitemap mostly does almost nothing for most sites. Check your log files to see if Google has been accessing your website. You can see this through Webmaster Tools too. If you see Google- relax. It will happen.

Answer (score 1):

As closetnoc suggested in comments, time is a virtue when it comes to indexing.

However, you appear to be using a free web hosting service that is serving some very intrusive adverts, even resulting in redirection!? This could very well be the cause of the problem.

Comment: There is no such thing as free! ;-)

Answer (score 1):

I remember a few months back creating a new web account for someone using the 000webhost provider. All I added was a simple index.htm page that displayed a paragraph of text. After actually testing the domain online that the index page is on, an advertisement that I didn't ask for popped up after the correct text loaded on the screen.

Ok, what you need to understand is that when you submit pages to google's index, *it does not necessarily mean they will be indexed*. Google will check through the URLs to make sure the content on the pages meet their webmaster quality guidelines and if it does, then the page will likely be indexed eventually.

You can attempt to speed things up by selecting the gear icon at the top-right hand of the webmaster tools page and choose "site settings" and select to specify a crawling rate instead of letting google manage it, and move the slider to the right.

If you have done all that, then I'd give google at least a good week to see what happens. If there are major issues, I'm sure google will either email you or webmaster tools will have a message waiting for you in your account.

And when you search for your website, use the most important keywords your site is about or you can search for the website url itself.

I think also, using site:example.com as a search query will list every page in a domain that is indexed. Just replace example.com with your website domain name.